# How to avoid using JSON data by some Kotlin functionality?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am making a simple calculation android game using kotlin for learning purposes, in which I have operators and a set of missions in each of the operator, as of now I have all the information about each of the operator and its missions written in a JSON file. How can I avoid using JSON as it is making it quite slow? (Using data class or object or something else...)
And what can be a smart way to easily translate that JSON code into that suggested way without writing all the things in that format again one by one?

The file is something like:

```
   [
  {
    "operator": "addition",
    "inputCounts": 2,
    "outputCounts": 1,
    "totalMissions": 5,
    "missions": [
      {
        "operator": "addition",
        "operatorCode": 0,
        "missionNumber": 1,
        "levelName":"mission1addition",
        "inputCounts": 2,
        "outputCounts": 1,
        "inputsMin": [
          0,
          0
        ],
        "inputsMax": [
          10,
          10
        ],
        "outputsLimit": false,
        "outputsMin": 0 ,
        "outputsMax": 20,
        "missionTagline": "tagline"


      },...................................
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please post your code, an example of your json file would help a lot towards giving you better answers here

Comment: JSON is just a format. What do you mean by "it's making it quite slow"?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin reading JSON by opening the JSON file, deserializing it, I think that is taking too much time and it is increasing the startup time as it is used in the main activity.

Comment: How did you measure this assumption? And how big is your JSON?
Instead of posting JSON contents, it would be more useful to post how do you parse it.